# Why are my settings saved in this situation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, settings.settings

I am rewriting my current program to make use of MVVM, and I am very much a beginned at MVVM - I feel very overwhelmed with it, so I apologise if this is obvious... What is happening is a good thing, not a bad thing... But I want to understand WHY it is happening. :)

I have only something very basic right now. I have my viewmodel and I have started putting together a model for looking at the values stored in properties.settings.default...

Here is a method from my viewmodel:

```
private static void UpgradeApplicationSettingsIfNecessary()
{
    // Application settings are stored in a subfolder named after the full #.#.#.# version number of the program. This means that when a new version of the program is installed, the old settings will not be available.
    // Fortunately, there's a method called Upgrade() that you can call to upgrade the settings from the old to the new folder.
    // We control when to do this by having a boolean setting called 'NeedSettingsUpgrade' which is defaulted to true. Therefore, the first time a new version of this program is run, it will have its default value of true.
    // This will cause the code below to call "Upgrade()" which copies the old settings to the new.
    // It then sets "NeedSettingsUpgrade" to false so the upgrade won't be done the next time.

    UserSetting Setting = new UserSetting();
    if (Setting.NeedSettingsUpgrade)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Settings Upgraded");
        Setting.NeedSettingsUpgrade = false;
    }
}
```

(Yep, it was borrowed code from somewhere). Essentially, I have a setting stored in settings.settings which defaults to true. If its true, I upgrade usersettings so that they persist between versions. (I already have my version incrementing with when program was built).

Here is my model:

```
class UserSetting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool needSettingsUpgrade;

    //Initiates the instance.
    public UserSetting()
    {
        NeedSettingsUpgrade = Properties.Settings.Default.NeedSettingsUpgrade;
    }

    public bool NeedSettingsUpgrade
    {
        get
        {
            return needSettingsUpgrade;
        }
        set
        {
            needSettingsUpgrade = value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            OnPropertyChanged("NeedSettingsUpgrade");
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So... I thought that I was going to have to at some point write:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.NeedSettingsUpgrade = false;
```

However that isnt the case. I added in the messagebox to the view model so that I could see if the setting was being saved or not, and it was. I build the program (giving it a new version number and hence resetting settings.settings back to defaults, so NeedSettingsUpgrade was true). I ran the program, saw the messagebox and closed it. Then I ran it again without rebuilding, and I see no messagebox until I rebuild and get a new version number.

Can you explain to me why I don't ned to add that extra line of code to store the false value into the usersetting? Why is it being updated to false? I can't for the life of me work out why!

Again, this is behaving how I want it to, just not how I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a complete code example, it's hard to know for sure what is going on, as well as to be sure one completely understands what you're even asking. However, based on your description:

> I ran the program, saw the messagebox and closed it. Then I ran it again without rebuilding, and I see no messagebox until I rebuild and get a new version number.

That strongly suggests that the `UpgradeApplicationSettingsIfNecessary()` method is being executed:

```
private static void UpgradeApplicationSettingsIfNecessary()
{
    // Application settings are stored in a subfolder named after the full #.#.#.# version number of the program. This means that when a new version of the program is installed, the old settings will not be available.
    // Fortunately, there's a method called Upgrade() that you can call to upgrade the settings from the old to the new folder.
    // We control when to do this by having a boolean setting called 'NeedSettingsUpgrade' which is defaulted to true. Therefore, the first time a new version of this program is run, it will have its default value of true.
    // This will cause the code below to call "Upgrade()" which copies the old settings to the new.
    // It then sets "NeedSettingsUpgrade" to false so the upgrade won't be done the next time.

    UserSetting Setting = new UserSetting();
    if (Setting.NeedSettingsUpgrade)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Settings Upgraded");
        Setting.NeedSettingsUpgrade = false;
    }
}
```

Not only does that method set the `NeedSettingsUpgrade` property to `false`, you even have a comment that describes this in detail.

Then in the setter for that property:

```
set
{
    needSettingsUpgrade = value;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    OnPropertyChanged("NeedSettingsUpgrade");
}
```

You call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`.

> Can you explain to me why I don't ned to add that extra line of code to store the false value into the usersetting? Why is it being updated to false?

From the above, it should be obvious why you don't need any additional code "to store the false value into the usersetting". The `UserSetting.NeedSettingsUpdate` property is being explicitly set by the code you posted.

Now, it's possible you are *actually* wondering why you don't need to actually set the `Properties.Settings.Default.NeedSettingsUpgrade` property before calling the `Save()` method.

That, no one can answer without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without one, it is not possible to explain why you don't need any additional code to do that.

What *can* be said, based on your description, is that the property is obviously getting set *somewhere*. Further, based on your description, it seems most likely that one of two things is true:

1. You are setting the `Properties.Settings.Default.NeedSettingsUpgrade` property to `false` in the `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()` method.
2. The `Properties.Settings.Default.NeedSettingsUpgrade` property is bound somewhere to the `UserSetting.NeedSettingsUpdate` property and getting set that way.

Since the #2 option works only if you go ahead and call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` *again* after setting the `UserSetting.NeedSettingsUpdate` property (since the setter calls `Save()` before it raises the notification event), my money is on #1. That means you've overridden the method somewhere and set the `NeedSettingsUpgrade` setting property to `false`.

But without seeing that code, it's impossible to know for sure.